# check for duplicates in enum

Tags: c, math, enums

Assuming I have the following enum:

```
enum {
  PARM1 = 1,
  PARM2,
  PARM3,
  PARM_MAX
};
```

I can add new members in it, but I want to make sure in compile-time, if possible, that all the members are consecutively incrementing and there is no duplicates. I'm wondering how to verify this in C code. I believe this is a math task.

Comment: Create an array of all possible elements. Then run your favorite duplicate-finding algorithm on it. But apparently it is guaranteed by the C standard, so I see no point..

Comment: Your definition does not have any duplicates, and all its members are incrementing consecutively. What is there to check?

Comment: What's the point of verifying compile-time constants at runtime?

Comment: At run-time there are no enums. Only `int` constant values. Why would one want this at all? Duplicate enums can be checked at compile-time, resp. before that.

Comment: All constants are defined in the same portion of code. You should have enough discipline to not have two identical values. Not clear what your actual problem is.

Comment: @Olaf: > Duplicate enums can be checked at compile-time, resp. before that.  How can this be done? The enums I care about are sort of IDs of kernel modules, and when IDs overlap, the module fails to load and register, so I want to ensure that all IDs, which are allocated by a module's developer, do not duplicate. Yes, there's a discipline developers must follow, however I want to have extra check in place.

Comment: @Mark: What keeps you from writing a clang-extension to do this? Or a simple  Python program? You definitively cannot at run-time without additional error-prone overhead. Maybe you should inform what enums are? The actual question is: why would one want to do this? From your comment, it is clear you have an XY-problem.

Comment: @Olaf, you mentioned that duplicate enums can be checked at compile time. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Mark: I already did! Read and _understand_ my comments. Do research. But also read what I (and others) actually wrote. Hint "XY-problem".

Comment: It might improve the question to give an example of the "bad code" you want to detect

Answer (score 1):

If you use that enum declaration, the numbers will be

```
enum {
  PARM1 = 1,
  PARM2,    /* = 2  */
  PARM3,    /* = 3  */
  PARM_MAX  /* = 4  */
};
```

It is not necessary to check this, all the compilers use this implementation.

Like Cubbi says in [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum) :

> If enumerator is followed by = constant-expression, its value is the
>   value of that constant expression. If enumerator is not followed by =
>   constant-expression, its value is the value one greater than the value
>   of the previous enumerator in the same enumeration. The value of the
>   first enumerator (if it does not use = constant-expression) is zero.

Comment: It is completely legal to have two enum-constants with the same value.

Comment: Yes, but by default two enum-constants have consecutive values.

Comment: That seems not to be the point of the question. But then, I'm not sure if OP himself knows what his problem is (or if there is one at all - I also can't see one).